# Broken drop down menu using Bootstrap and navwalker class

Tags: menus, walker, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap + navwalker class and my problem is that the drop down menu doesn't expand when clicking.
The odd thing is that if I change the URL from where the bootstrap.js is fetched to an incorrect URL the drop down start to work, but then i of course get a warning that this file cannot be found.
IBelow is the code I have.

Code

```
functions.php
<?php function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{ 
// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
// For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );

// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');

// Register Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus( array(
'header' => 'header',
'footer' => 'footer',
) );
?>
```

header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" <?php echo (is_admin_bar_showing()) ? ' style="top: 32px;"' : ''; ?>>
<div class="container">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>"><?php bloginfo('name')?></a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

 <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'header',
            'theme_location'    => 'header',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );
    ?>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What is the code you're using to add bootstrap's js?  If everything works how you intended it to when you add an invalid URL then why don't you just remove the line you added?  Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed to put 4 spaces on part of the code for functions file, is the information above now what you need to see?

Comment: Yes I do get a console error when the URL is wrong _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)_

Answer (score 0):

Found that I was including the Bootstrap.min.js from the footer.php and this caused the issues. When the URL was wrong in functions.php then the js called from Footer made the menu show correct but then gave a console error for the incorrect URL called in functions.php, while when both were called correctly they clashed.

By removing one of them it works fine.